# Error creating dynamo db table Hash Key not specified in Attribute Definitions

Tags: spring-boot, amazon-dynamodb, aws-java-sdk-2.x

I am getting an error for creating a dynamo DB table using AWS SDK for Java 2.0. The hash key is specified but still getting error

```
    @Bean
  ApplicationRunner applicationRunner(DynamoDbClient dynamoDbClient) {
    return args -> {
      dynamoDbClient.listTables().tableNames().forEach(System.out::println);

  CreateTableRequest createTableRequest =
      CreateTableRequest.builder()
          .keySchema(
              KeySchemaElement.builder().keyType(KeyType.HASH).attributeName("id").build())
          .attributeDefinitions(
              AttributeDefinition.builder()
                  .attributeName("campaign_name")
                  .attributeType(ScalarAttributeType.S)
                  .build())
          .provisionedThroughput(
              ProvisionedThroughput.builder()
                  .readCapacityUnits(5L)
                  .writeCapacityUnits(5L)
                  .build())
          .tableName("campaign")
          .build();
  try {
    dynamoDbClient.createTable(createTableRequest);
    dynamoDbClient.listTables().tableNames().forEach(System.out::println);
  } catch (DynamoDbException e) {
    System.err.println(e.getMessage());
  }
};
```

}

Error:

> Hash Key not specified in Attribute Definitions.  Type unknown. (Service: DynamoDb, Status Code: 400, Request ID: bed4b8c3-f312-4a9d-8d7b-a2184dacce54)

I am trying to create a table with key and non key column

```
@Bean
ApplicationRunner applicationRunner(DynamoDbClient dynamoDbClient) {
    return args -> {
      dynamoDbClient.listTables().tableNames().forEach(System.out::println);

      CreateTableRequest createTableRequest =
          CreateTableRequest.builder()
              .attributeDefinitions(
                  AttributeDefinition.builder()
                      .attributeName("id")
                      .attributeType(ScalarAttributeType.S)
                      .build(),
                  AttributeDefinition.builder()
                      .attributeName("name")
                      .attributeType(ScalarAttributeType.S)
                      .build())
              .keySchema(
                  KeySchemaElement.builder()
                      .keyType(KeyType.HASH)
                      .attributeName("campaign_id")
                      .build())
              .provisionedThroughput(
                  ProvisionedThroughput.builder()
                      .readCapacityUnits(5L)
                      .writeCapacityUnits(5L)
                      .build())
              .tableName("campaign")
              .build();
      try {
        dynamoDbClient.createTable(createTableRequest);
        dynamoDbClient.listTables().tableNames().forEach(System.out::println);
      } catch (DynamoDbException e) {
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
      }
    };
  }
```

Error - The number of attributes in key schema must match the number of attributesdefined in attribute definitions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need to add a `AttributeDefinition` for your `KeySchemeElement` as well.

Try adding the following to your `attributeDefinitions` call

```
AttributeDefinition.builder()
              .attributeName("campaign_id")
              .attributeType(ScalarAttributeType.S)
              .build()
```

Comment: Thanks, I am trying to create a table with key and non-key column

Comment: In your case, the only required `AttributeDefinition` is for your key. DynamoDB does not require you to define attributes for non-key columns.

Answer (score 0):

I think campaign_id is the HASH key and that's the one that needs to be in the AttributeDefinitions.

```
              AttributeDefinition.builder()
                  .attributeName("campaign_id")
                  .attributeType(ScalarAttributeType.S)
                  .build(),
```